# How to put the word <<required>> in the field of a required field and "choose a country" in the country field in an ubnound form

Tags: ms-access

How do I display the word <<required>> in the field of a required field  and "choose a country" in the country field in an unbound form of an access fillable form.

Comment: I am new to access, so is this impossible to be achieved in access? Its just the caption that I need

Comment: Never mind, I misread the question.

Comment: Try DefaultValue property.

Comment: default property it didnt work for it.

Comment: The default property value will display in the control when the form opens. You can use that or just add a label next to the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property **Format** of the textbox:

```
@,"<required>"
```

Replace comma with semicolon if that is your local separator.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is whether you want "<>" and "choose a country" being the actual values of these controls.

I would add transparent background labels on top of the controls. Set the `On Got Focus` event of the underlying controls to make the corresponding label invisible and set the `On Click` event of the label to set the focus on the underlying control. You can also use the `On Lost Focus` event of the controls to see if you should turn the label visible again or not.